# How can I specify a different domain name in Ansible inventory

Tags: ansible

I am using a Linux VM managed many Linux boxes (in a different domain), I find it annoying to use FQDN for each individual servers, because our internal domain name is very long.

For example

```
[web]
serve1.part.one.of.very.long.internal.domain.name.com
anotherserver.part.one.of.very.long.internal.domain.name.com
```

Is there a way to specify a default domain for groups of servers in inventory? I tried adding `andible_domain` variable in inventory file as a variable but did not work.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

By default Ansible will assume that your `inventory_hostname` (the first string on the line in the inventory file) is what you would use to connect to that.

You can, however, always override this by using [`ansible_host`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_inventory.html) (or `ansible_ssh_host` in older versions) which is useful if for some reason that's not the FQDN of the host or the domain for the host isn't in your DNS search domain list.

So you could do something like this:

```
[all:vars]
host_domain=part.one.of.very.long.internal.domain.name.com
ansible_host="{{inventory_hostname}}.{{host_domain}}"

[web]
server1
anotherserver
```

Comment: If you use that, do you still require the domain in the host_vars folder names? Edit: Nevermind, just tried it, works without the domain in the foldername.

Comment: This solution will lead to problems when using delegation. The problem is that ansible_host will also be resolved for the delegate_to host and inventory_hostname "always reflects the original host for the task". ie: delegate_to does not work anymore because it always resolves to the original host. I'm still searching for a bullet proof solution...

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different version of the answer from @ydaetskcoR to avoid breaking delegation by utilizing inventory_hostname**_short** instead of inventory_hostname:

```
[all:vars]
host_domain=part.one.of.very.long.internal.domain.name.com
ansible_host="{{inventory_hostname_short}}.{{host_domain}}"

[web]
server1
anotherserver
```

From [Ansible docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html):

> **inventory_hostname_short**
> The short version of inventory_hostname, is the first section after splitting it via .. As an example, for the inventory_hostname of [www.example.com](http://www.example.com), www would be the inventory_hostname_short **This is affected by delegation**, so it will reflect the ‘short name’ of the delegated host

while inventory_hostname...

> **is not** affected by delegation, it always reflects the original host for the task

Therefore, the problem with `ansible_host="{{inventory_hostname}}.{{host_domain}}"` is that that it resolves back to the original host when trying to delegate the task to another host with `delegate_to`. This was also elaborated on [GitHub/ansible](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/71198#issuecomment-673007842).